# Tcl - encoding convertfrom ascii

Tags: encoding, tcl, asn.1

I was looking on asn.tcl file i downloaded and it used encoding convertfrom ascii.
When i run this command it fails on ascii encoding (it works with utf-8).
Anyone know how to use it with ascii?

Thanks.

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. There is literally zero difference when you compare ALL of the characters in ASCII with the same characters in UTF-8. The difference comes form extended ASCII but extended ASCII is not called ASCII because there are many variants. There's Windows-1252, there's Latin-1 etc. They're all, like UTF-8, superset of ASCII

Answer (score 2):

ASN.1 would usually be best handled as binary data from the get go, and the encoding of the strings contained within it would be something that the keys for those strings ought to define. In the fallback case where you don't know what encoding to use, the encoding `iso8859-1` is the first choice as that's the special one that doesn't do horrible mangling of binary data. (It's because it exactly maps bytes in the range 0–255 to characters in the range U+000000–U+0000FF, which is both trivial and non-lossy.) *Guessing* the encoding otherwise is hard, sometimes impossible.

I wouldn't want to parse ASN.1 by hand. Use the [tcllib package for it](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/asn/asn.html). With ordinary tags, it can do the majority of the work for you:

```
package require asn

set f [open "mydata.ber" "rb"]
set myData [read $f]
close $f
# ...
# Data being parsed is now in $myData variable
# I assume that we've reached a string in the parsing of it
# ...
asn::asnGetString myData myString
puts "String parsed was '$myString'"
```

However, I guess that anyone using it still needs to understand ASN.1 at the logical level.